# Column Header Flyout menu cutting off

Tags: quick-launch, popup

The ascending/descending/filter flyout menu that appears when you click on the column headers on Views is being cut off by left nav (quick launch menu).  Not sure how to resolve this.  I see the flyout is using this class:

I tried adding this style to the page directly (in Content Editor webpart):

.ms-MenuUIPopupBody .ms-MenuUIPopupScreen {
    z-index:1000 !important;}

I have attached a screenshot showing what is happening.  Thanks for any suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the designer had added this custom style:

## MSO_ContentTable { height:600px;overflow:hidden !important; }

Changed it to height:auto and overflow:inherit

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem you had except only with certain lists. I was able to find a fix for it.

Try:

```
.ms-rte-layoutszone-inner {
    overflow:visible !important;
}
```